# Limitar acceso a una url de mi sitio web

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Necesito limitar el acceso a una seccion específica de mi web, a los usuarios que no dispongan de un correo con un dominio específico.

La web de la que hablo es un wordpress y he estado buscando si existe alguna opción en concreto, pero no localizo la que me pueda servir. Creo que elaborando algo en functions.php, no debería de ser complejo pero para salir del paso estaba buscando alguna solución ya desarrollada.

Se os ocurre algo a mayores de esto o sabéis si lo estoy enfocando bien?

Gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Creo que deberías buscar una solución ya desarrollada, después leer el [tour] y luego leer [ask] :-)